# How can I move a file from a linux computer to my mac laptop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, osx

I have a file in my Linux work computer that I need on my personal Mac laptop and I wanted to know how I could get that to my mac computer. I can't email it to myself because it's a dmg file and it's too large via email. How can I send this file to myself using terminal commands? Also I have no administrative capabilities so I can't use sudo

Comment: Are the two machines on the same network and can you use `scp`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync -avz --progress /path/to/file user@host:/path/to/destination` or `scp /path/to/file user@host:/path/to/destination`